# Using Capybara for AJAX integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara

I am using Capybara for rails integration tests. When it comes to AJAX requests, I am getting the following error:

```
Capybara::TimeoutError: failed to resynchronize, ajax request timed out
```

Any idea what's wrong and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue once I upgraded my selenium/capybara gems. There is some AJAX synchronization logic that is causing this, so I just disabled it within my test hook.

```
Before do
  page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
end
```

Comment: That bit of code goes in features/step_definitions/mydefiniation.rb

Comment: unknown option: {:resynchronize=>false} (ArgumentError) ./features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:55:in `/^I am on (.+)$/'

Answer (score 2):

If you are on rail 3

change this in your gem file.

gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git', :branch =>'async_is_my_bitch'

then do bundle update.

This will solve it.

Comment: This is now in the current Capybara releases -- no need to get the branch anymore.