# Capybara use Internet Explorer as browser rather than Firefox

Tags: browser, capybara

Hi is it possible to tell Capybara to use IE instead of always defaulting to Firefox?

I have to write some automated tests but the business only supports Internet Explorer so I need the tests to be run on this browser.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you make IE your default browser on that machine??

Comment: Tried that but when I run the capybara tests Firefox comes up, it's like there's an override setting for the browser somewhere in the Capybara framework. It must be configurable but how?

Answer (score 4):

As marc_s suggested in the comments, you could try making IE the default browser on your test machine.

I also see some google hits about using Capybara with [Selenium (remote control)](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

If you're interested, check [the Selenium docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#executing-selenium-ide-tests-on-different-browsers) for how to specify the browser.

**Edit** It seems the tutorial I posted before was Rack-only.  Not sure, but maybe this will work instead:

http://www.johng.co.uk/2010/10/13/run_capybara_and_cucumber_features_in_internet_explorer_on_remote_windows/

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://192.168.1.37:3000"
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    :url => "http://192.168.1.127:4444/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => :internet_explorer)
end
```

It still requires Selenium.

**Edit 2:**

If you get this error:

> Capybara::TimeoutError: failed to resynchronize, ajax request timed out

Then try adding this code to `features/step_definitions/mydefiniation.rb`:

```
Before do
  page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
end
```

See this question about that specific problem: [Using Capybara for AJAX integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689914/using-capybara-for-ajax-integration-tests)

Comment: Thanks f0r the suggestions but these examples are for rack based applications. The application under test will not be a rack app.

Comment: @logi: Found another example.  The comments under the blog post mention "if you are using Rack, do this instead", so maybe this will work without Rack :)

Comment: I tried this myself, and it works as far as opening an IE8 window and running through the automation tests, but I get an error saying `"failed to resynchronize, ajax request timed out (Capybara::TimeoutError)"`

Comment: @VGambit: Maybe this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689914/using-capybara-for-ajax-integration-tests

Comment: @VGambit: Edited answer to cover that.  Thanks for the feedback!  Remember to upvote that other question and/or answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ->

ignore_mode    = opts.delete(:introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains) != false

Goto -> External Libraries- selenium-webdriver - lib - selenium - webdriver - ie - bridge.rb

Update module IE -> def initialize

It contains -

ignore_mode    = opts.delete(:introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains)

just add != false so that it becomes ->

ignore_mode    = opts.delete(:introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains) != false