# cucumber, capybara 1.1.3 and internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cucumber, capybara, selenium-rc

I am looking for a general strategy to use Cucumber tests in a Linux environment to test against an Internet Explorer browser. I have seen a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715973/capybara-use-internet-explorer-as-browser-rather-than-firefox) but that does not seem to apply to capybara 1.1.3.

I was hoping to use capybara to avoid using Selenium directly and the subsequent cost (speed, environmental dependencies) of not using headless tests, but it seems that may not be possible. I want to avoid using both capybara and selenium.

A nice compromise may be [Ross Patterson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241753/ross-patterson) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573839/1827312) to a Selenium based question:

> Headless browsers are a bad idea. They get you some testing, but nothing like what a real user will see, and they mask lots of problems that only real browsers encounter. You're infinitely better off using a "headed" browser (i.e., anything but HTMLUnit) on a headless environment (e.g., Windows, or Linux with XVFB).

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Just as a follow up, Capybara 2.0.0 seems to work well with Selenium 2 and its [Selenium Standalone Server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer) and [IEDriverServer](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)