# Capybara not waiting for ajax request to complete

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to test selecting an option from select tag (these options are fetched from a remote database server). During normal interation with the website, it does not take more than a fraction of a second to populate this dropdown. However, when I run the following test,

```
    When /^(?:|I )select "([^"]*)" from "([^"]*)" in search form$/ do |value, field|
      within "#select_container" do
        save_and_open_page
        page.should have_css("#criteria_div_code > option:nth-child(10)")
        select(value, :from => field)
      end 
    end
```

I get the following error,

`expected css "#criteria_div_code > option:nth-child(10)" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)`

The dropdown is populated with at least 20 options and so I just test for the presence of the 10th option (for now).

`save_and_open_page` shows that only one option (default option) exists instead of at least 10 and hence the "ExpectionNotMetError" comes up.

`Capybara.default_wait_time = 30`  - Ample time for the lists to get populated.

Isn't capybara waiting for the ajax call to finish?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tagged the scenario as `@javascript`?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check my response to setting timeouts for ajax resynchronization [Using Capybara for AJAX integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689914/using-capybara-for-ajax-integration-tests/9569058#9569058). Resynchronization timeout defaults to 10secs and if your response does not return before that time, you will not get any responses especially if you have set :resynchronize to false in your configurations. below is a snippet to set that timeout

```
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :resynchronization_timeout => 1000)
 end
```

NOTE: if you previously set :resynchronize to false, you need to set this to true.

Comment: With `Capybara` version 2.0.3 this causes this error: `unknown option: {:resynchronization_timeout=>1000} (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @etagwerker you are right. The :synchronize options has been removed from Selenium driver and as such will probably not work for newer version of Selenium driver. The above solution was for Capybara versions less than 2.0.3 accompanied with an older version of Selenium driver.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to user js driver for ajax testing,

```
describe 'some stuff which requires js', :js => true do
  it 'will use the default js driver'
  it 'will switch to one specific driver', :driver => :celerity
end
```

Also note the following line - Capybara can block and wait for Ajax requests to finish after you’ve interacted with the page. To enable this behaviour, set the :resynchronize driver option to true.